# Simulate X11 KeyPress in C#

Tags: c#, .net, vnc

I am using RemoteViewing VNC Server library for .NET to implement some custom VNC behaviour. (Send custom images instead of the desktop under certain conditions etc...)

Now I am adding keyboard functionality, and the library has this keyChange event which provides the X11 KeySym of the key and a boolean indicating wether it is pressed. So I want to fire a function when this event is raised that will pass this key to the local computer. I am however having a hard time finding a solution that will translate these X11 keysym to something Windows understands.

I would really appreciate it if someone could provide some info on how to write the logic that will send these X11 keysyms to Windows.

Comment: What about [SendKeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Does not seem to understand X11 KeySymbols.... The problem is not in simulating the keys, but in translating the symbols to something that i.e. SendKeys could understand.

Comment: Ok i didn't understand your question.See if my answer helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if I understand it right, you just want to translate the X11 KeySymbols to windows keycodes. I think you just have to create a dictionary, using as key the values found in `keysymdef.h` (you've got it [here](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/keysymdef.h) for example) and as values the keycodes understood by [SendKeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx).

Hope this puts you on the track.

Comment: I mainly posted this question hoping to find a way to prevent having to do exactly that, since I need support for at least alphabetic, cyrillic, Korean, Japanese and Chinese, but thank you for your answer!

Comment: Well..i'm sorry @larzz11 but i don't think there's another way. X11 defined it keys using its own criteria,and windows did the same,no direct way to translate that i know of :)

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Took me a couple of hours, but it works now